# How do we interpret the output of the Naive Bayes' classifier in e1071 package?

Tags: r, naive-bayes

I am executing the code given at [Sentiment analysis with machine learning in R](https://www.r-bloggers.com/sentiment-analysis-with-machine-learning-in-r/).

While executing this code, I am trying to examine the contents of the object 'classifier'. The conditional probability for 'about' was given in the following format -

> ```
>                                  about 
>      as.factor(tweets[1:10, 2])  [,1]      [,2]                  
>                        negative  0.0 0.0000000
>                        positive  0.2 0.4472136
> ```

From the formula of Naive Bayes, I could figure out that the first column is probability of getting 'about' with 'negative' and 'positive' sentiment respectively. But what does the second column mean?

Could you please help with that?